# How to fix linker error (LNK2019) in different projects inside one solution

Tags: c++, reference, linker, linker-errors, multi-project

I have one solution, and two projects inside the solution (Project1 & Project2). They both are console programs. Inside Project1 we have functions.h with function "foo()" and functions.cpp with the implementation of this function.
How can I use this function in Project2 without copying a code or using DLLs? I already add the reference to Project1 in Project2 and add Project1 folder into "Additional include directories" in Project2 settings.
"Link library dependencies" is set to true

Comment: you can't link programs together, you need to use a library

Comment: it asks me for ".lib" file, I don't have one in a Project1

Comment: I deleted my comment. @AlanBirtles is correct. You can't link native executables. One of these projects need to be a library. Setting one to be dependent on the other won't help. If you need to share functionality between executables make a third library project with the common code.

Comment: am i need to create a new "library" project, copy code from Project1, and connect it to Project2?
or there is a better way?

Comment: Create a new library project that will contain the common code from both executables. Refactor to move (I mean move not copy) the code from the executable projects to the library project that will be needed in both executables. Link both executable projects to the library.